# Using GitHub Actions to automatically update the repo's submodules

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-submodules

Title says it all. I tried using a bunch of different git commands like `git submodule update --remote --merge` and `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` which work fine on my computer, but not when it's run on GitHub actions.
I tried adding `git status` to the workflow and the status just shows "Up to date with origin/master, nothing to commit" or something like that.

Comment: Did you end up solving this @ma1234

Comment: No, I just abandoned submodules and instead used a GitHub Action to just copy over the files normally.

Answer (score 36):

### If you need to auto update references to your submodules via GitHub actions:

Create a new workflow in your parent repository that will synchronize references:

```yaml
name: 'Submodules Sync'

on:
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab or through HTTP API
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  sync:
    name: 'Submodules Sync'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    # Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}
        submodules: true

    # Update references
    - name: Git Submodule Update
      run: |
        git pull --recurse-submodules
        git submodule update --remote --recursive

    - name: Commit update
      run: |
        git config --global user.name 'Git bot'
        git config --global user.email 'bot@noreply.github.com'
        git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}
        git commit -am "Auto updated submodule references" && git push || echo "No changes to commit"
```

where

- CI_TOKEN is a security token variable in GitHub that have 'Read-Write' access to the parent repository, and 'Read' access to submodule repositories.

---

In the child (submodule) GitHub action notify the parent about changes.

```yaml
name: 'Submodule Notify Parent'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main    

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  notify:
    name: 'Submodule Notify Parent'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Use the Bash shell regardless whether the GitHub Actions runner is ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, or windows-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
    - name: Github REST API Call
      env:
        CI_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CI_TOKEN }}
        PARENT_REPO: <my_organization/my-app>
        PARENT_BRANCH: develop
        WORKFLOW_ID: <9999999>
      run: |
        curl -fL --retry 3 -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token ${{ env.CI_TOKEN }}" https://api.github.com/repos/${{ env.PARENT_REPO }}/actions/workflows/${{ env.WORKFLOW_ID }}/dispatches -d '{"ref":"${{ env.PARENT_BRANCH }}"}'
```

where

- PARENT_REPO - name of the parent repository as it is in Github (my_org/my_app or just my_app if there is no organization).
- WORKFLOW_ID - parent Wofklow ID to call via rest API. To find it run curl using your `CI_TOKEN`:

  ```
  curl -X GET -H "Authorization: token $CI_TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/$PARENT_REPO/actions/workflows
  ```

Repeat the workflow creation for every submodule.

---

P.S. For me it works very stable. Please add information about existing github actions with the above logic if there is any.

Comment: If you had no way to run workflows on the submodule, could you just run the first workflow on a schedule?

Comment: Hi @ma1234, yes, it is possible to set up a schedule for workflow run, please refer to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events   Though in this case there will be time intervals when the parent branch is out of sync with submodule references.

Answer (score 22):

A much better option today is to utilize Dependabot to auto create PRs for submodules.

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem

A sample that checks daily if a submodule has been updated:
In `.github/dependabot.yml`

```yaml
version: 2

updates:
  - package-ecosystem: gitsubmodule
    schedule:
        interval: "daily"
    directory: /
```

Comment: This is indeed the better option, but it has one drawback : it is not run on Saturday and Sunday (see https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#scheduleinterval).

Comment: woah, @MarcWrobel definitely misleading to be labeled "daily".

Comment: Yeah, what's GitHub doing there? Bizarre. At least it's mentioned in the docs I suppose.

Answer (score 19):

You can achieve this with a single action in the submodule repository:

```
name: Send submodule updates to parent repo

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with: 
          repository: org/parent_repository
          token: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_TOKEN_GITHUB }}
          submodules: true

      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote

      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions - update submodules"
          git add --all
          git commit -m "Update submodules" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push
```

You need to:

- adjust the name of the parent repository (here, I used `org/parent_repository` as an example).
- [create a private access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). with sufficient permissions to write in your parent repository and [save it as a repository secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) (under the name `PRIVATE_TOKEN_GITHUB` in my example above)

With this action, every push on the `main` branch in the submodule repository will result in a commit pulling the update in the parent repository.

Comment: Remember to add submodules: 'true' below repository: in with:

Comment: Doesn't it kind of suck to have this global personal access token in this workflow @Droplet?

Comment: @EricCarmichael, it's a tough question, especially when framed so generally. Depends on your threat model. I can give two general answers, which may or may not apply well to your specific case: 1. It is generally considered safer/better practice to use the built-in GITHUB_TOKEN PAT **when possible** because it has restricted permissions & scope (but we don't have this option here). 2. It would be ideal if GitHub allowed us to create PAT with permissions linked to a specific repo, instead of all your repos.

Comment: Regarding my second point, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63296569/4439357 seems to propose an interesting alternative: use a deploy key instead of a PAT. I'll have a look and update my answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Another possible answer: I didn't mention it but in my organisation, we have a dedicated machine user (https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users) and we use its PAT for automation. In the worst case scenario, where someone steals the PAT, the damage is more limited

Comment: @Droplet thanks for all of the info! So a "Deploy key" can make commits and such?

Comment: Action runs successfully but the submodule is not updated. Shouldn't the step `git submodule update --recursive --remote` run on the parent repo? when i run this directly in the parent repo it updated the submodule. Should the PRIVATE_TOKEN be present in both repos? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `git submodule update` step has to run in the parent repo. But this is already the case if you set the "repository" option value correctly in the `actions/checkout` step, as documented in the answer.
The `PRIVATE_TOKEN` needs write access to the parent repo but should be in the secrets of the submodule repo, where this workflow lives.

Answer (score 8):

## Simple solution

You pull and update the submodules recursively and then commit to the repo.

```
name: Update submodules

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "update"
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote

      - name: Commit & push changes
        run: |
          git config --global user.name ${{ secrets.USER_NAME }}
          git config --global user.email ${{ secrets.USER_EMAIL }}
          git commit -am "Update submodules"
          git push
```

Instead of using Github secrets like `${{ secrets.USER_NAME }}` I just hard code my git credentials since I'm lazy, but I figured you might care about security.

Answer (score 1):

i try this it working for me

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: {owner}/repo
        token: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_TOKEN_GITHUB }}
        submodules: recursive

    - name: submodules recursively
      run: git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare your GitHub Action source with one like [`submodule-branch-check`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/submodule-branch-check), which does make at least a [`git submodule update`](https://github.com/jtmullen/submodule-branch-check-action/blob/0a86f27829721b64cc0a761e72905d8b5ac9e058/entrypoint.sh#L55).

Check if the `update --remote` is enough to pull from its own remote origin.

Answer (score 0):

it working for me, read acticle in here https://zenn.dev/ymmmtym/articles/dc741561759a49

```
name: Update submodules
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  update_submodules:
    name: Update submodules
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        token : ${{secrets.OOG_TOKEN}}
        submodules : true
    - name: Update submodules
      id: update
      run: git submodule update --remote --recursive 
    - name: Run git status
      id: status
      run: echo "::set-output name=status::$(git status -s)"
    - name: Add and commit files
      run: |
        git add .
        git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
        git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
        git commit -m "Update submodules at $(date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d TIME: %H:%M:%S")"
      if: ${{ steps.status.outputs.status }}
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        branch: dev
      if: ${{ steps.status.outputs.status && github.event_name == 'push' }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement @Droplet's solution! I extended it to update multiple parent repos that are using the submodule using a matrix like so:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master

jobs:
  update_parent_repos:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        parent_repo: [parent_repo_1, parent_repo_2]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with: 
          repository: myriadgenetics/${{ matrix.parent_repo }}
          token: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_TOKEN }}
          submodules: 'recursive'
      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote
      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions - update submodules"
          git add --all
          git commit -m "Update submodules" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push
```

You will have to use the correct label for the action runner for your use case if it isn't `ubuntu-latest`, update `parent_repo_1` and `parent_repo_2` to the names of the parent repos you want to update the submodule in, and use the correct token name for your use case. I for some reason had to include `submodules: 'recursive'` otherwise was running into issues when running the commands within "Pull & update submodules recursively".