# Trigger push main repo on submodule push using github workflows

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, cicd

As the title says, how do i trigger a push of the main repo (together with the updated changes of submodule) when there is a push only on submodule?

Comment: Would [this article](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-trigger-github-actions-on-submodule-updates/) help?

Comment: this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059629/8502320